# CSS <a> has a wrong color in Chrome, but in Explorer it is all right

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-5, internet-explorer-10

I have a problem with an ambiguous CSS compilation in different browsers. I want to have a different color for a link in the title of main news on the home page.

Generally I declare links in this way:

```
a:visited
{
    color: purple;
}
a :hover
{
    color: aqua;
}
```

But for mainNewsTitle link I declare this:

```
.mainNewsTitle a
{
    color:white;
}
.mainNewsTitle a :visited
{
    color:white;
}
```

I have this code in cshtml file:

```
@if (Model.MainNews[0].Title.Length > 40)
{
    <h2 id="mainNewsTitle1" class="mainNewsTitle"><a href="@Model.MainNews[0].Link" target="_blank">@Model.MainNews[0].Title.Substring(0, 40)...</a></h2>
}
else
{
    <h2 id="mainNewsTitle1" class="mainNewsTitle"><a href="@Model.MainNews[0].Link" target="_blank">@Model.MainNews[0].Title</a></h2>
}
```

In Internet Explorer, it displays the link right - white color.
In Google Chrome, it is blue and after visit it is purple.

Comment: I would start by removing the space here: `a :visited` -> `a:visited`. IE accidentally allows this, but it's actually invalid (or at least it doesn't mean what you think it means).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the space in `a :visited`; it's causing problems. With a space, you're trying to target any visited children of a, instead of targeting an a link that has already been visited.

```
.mainNewsTitle a {
    color:white;
}

.mainNewsTitle  a:visited {
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right. Thank you! I thought that It does not matter if I write space or this >. Because in MVC he does not ignore spaces in CSS. div .class1  means some class1 element, which is inside the div, but div.class1 means div, which has class name "class1".

Comment: Your first answer was right. :-D I had a space in `.mainNewsTitle a {color:white;}` and it was blue.

Answer (score 2):

A whitespace in a css declaration is a "descendant combinator".

[From w3c doc](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators)

> A descendant combinator is whitespace that separates two sequences of
>   simple selectors. A selector of the form "A B" represents an element B
>   that is an arbitrary descendant of some ancestor element A.

You are selecting any hovered element inside `a` elements.

To select anchor tags you should use `a:hover` instead of `a :hover` and `a:visited` instead of `a :visited`.